# Compact: if seq has subseq that converges. But why is "seq converges" not enough?

Tags: functional-analysis

Compact: if seq has subseq that converges. But why is "seq converges" not enough?

Particular confusion:

-Sequence converges can be demonstrateable. So why does one need to investigate subsequences?

-Sequence having convergent subsequence is definition of *sequentially compact* (which is not same as *compact*).

Still my notes defined:

Set $K$ is compact if every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence.

Is this an unclear definition?

Does one really require convergent subsequences in order to have compactness (not sequential compactness)?

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that two point $Y:=\{x,y\}$ in a topological space $X$ must be seq. compact.

If you define seq compact as ‘each sequence must be convergent’ you have that $Y$ is not seq. compact.

For example $a_{2n}:=x$ and $a_{2n-1}:=y$ is not convergent.